# Inconsistency with building an image from 2d array of pixels

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

I have data about the intensity values on a surface. It is in the form of (x-coord, y-coord, intensity(between 0 and 255)). Using this, I created a 2D array of pixels and got a grayscale image. I also got a grayscale image of the surface using an optical profiler. The two do not match for some reason.

Original image
[image: Original image]

When I tried the following, the two images did not match:

```
img = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(mat) , 'L')
img.show()
```

Image without multiplying 255
[image: Image without multiplying 255]

When I tried this, the images were still not the same but the contours were matching:

```
img = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(mat*255) , 'L')
img.show()
```

Image after multiplying by 255
[image: Image after multiplying by 255]

Is this just dumb luck or am I missing something?

I expect them to match perfectly without multiplying the array with 255. They don't, but when I multiply, they are somewhat similar.

Comment: what is the type of mat before casting? could it be some over/underflow? Do you do some process before converting? could it be that the error is from before this point? BTW, this has nothing to do with OpenCV, avoid using tags that are not part of the problem. Or do you want a solution with OpenCV?

Comment: Note that your original image is not greyscale, but actually greyscale + alpha, i.e. it has 2 channels - which is entirely pointless since there is nothing in the alpha channel, by the way. If you are reading it with PIL/Pillow, discard the alpha channel; like this `im = Image.open(...).convert('L')` If you are reading it with OpenCV, be sure to use `cv2.imread(..., cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)`

Comment: It turns out that the optical profiler was capturing raw data in a different setting. There is no real problem with the code! Thanks for the replies. I'm sorry for wasting your time.